# Serilog Ilogger custom properties

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, serilog, ilogger

I have found two seperate methods of adding custom properties to my Serilog log messages.

1. The Generic Microsoft Ilogger "Begin Scope"

   ```
    using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "MyVar", var } }))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"MyVar: {var} - My logging message...");
    }
   ```
2. The Serilog "Log Context"

   ```
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("MyVar", var))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"MyVar: {var} - My logging message...");
    }
   ```

Both work. However, now my 1 line logging message has increased to multiple lines due to this using statement wrapper and it will be everywhere in my code!

How can I get the log message back down to 1 line?

Do I write a separate log class, that instantiates the logger inside it? Otherwise I will be passing loggers into it via dependency injection?

Do I write an IDisposable adaptor class for ILogger?

Can I use ILoggerFactory?

Any help appreciated :)

I am using .NET 6.0

Comment: Do not use string interpolation in log messages and structured logging will make your problem go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would argue that there is not much profit to use the scopes to add data to single log, just log it and let [structured logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data) handle the rest.
2. You can switch to [`using` declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-declaration?view=msvc-170) if the scope allows it, so you will end up with 2 lines:

   ```
   using var logCtx = LogContext.Push(...); // or _logger.BeginScope
    _logger.LogInformation(...);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was previously using structured logging and it's easy but the JSON log message doesn't show the value, it shows the name of the objects. The value being hidden in the Properties object. "MessageTemplate":"MyVar: {var} Log message",
"Properties":{"var":"blahblahblah","SourceContext": .... I suppose a log viewer might make it easier to read?

Comment: @ScottishSmile yes, usually this is handled by the log viewer. They should expose collect and expose the properties correctly (which was usually the case in my experience).